# JSON.parse unexpected end of input error in NodeJS MailParser

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am executing a code in NodeJS child_process. 
I used MailParser of Andris9.
I used `console.log(JSON.stringify({obj:mail_object}));` to get the data of mail_object to the parent.

In the parent, I have this code, `JSON.parse(retVal);`.
The error came up is "Unexpected end of Input".
This error only shows when the email I received is having an attachment.
If the email doesnt have attachment, there is no error.

Here is the parent method,

```
getEmails(){
    let workerProcess = child_process.spawn('node', [basePath+'imports/workers/retrieveEmail.js']);
    workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        try{
            let retVal = new Buffer(data).toString();
            retVal = JSON.parse(retVal);
            console.log(retVal);
            if(typeof retVal.err == "undefined"){
                console.log(retVal.obj.from[0].address);
                Fiber(function () {
                    var objs = [];
                    if (typeof retVal.obj.attachments !== "undefined") {
                        console.log("Test passed");
                        retVal.obj.attachments.forEach(function (attachment) {
                            let future = new Future();

                            Fiber(function () {
                                Files.write(attachment.content, {
                                    fileName: attachment.fileName,
                                    type: attachment.contentType
                                }, function (error, fileRef) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        future.throw(new Meteor.Error(500, error.message));
                                    } else {
                                        ...
                                    }
                                });
                            }).run();
                            var bool = true;
                            if (bool = future.wait())
                                objs.push(bool);
                        });
                    }
                    ...
                }).run();
            }else{
                console.log(retVal.err);
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
},
```

I removed some unnecessary codes.
Here is my retrieveEmail.js,

```
...
    client.on("retr", function (status, msgnumber, data, rawdata) {
        if (status === true) {
            var mailparser = new MailParser({
                streamAttachments: false
            });
            var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now());
            mailparser.on("attachment", function (attachment, mail) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify({err:"testpassed1"}));
            });
            mailparser.on("end", function (mail_object) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify({err:"testpassed2"}));
                console.log(JSON.stringify({obj:mail_object}));
            });
            mailparser.write(data);
            mailparser.end();
            client.dele(msgnumber);
        } else {
            console.log("RETR failed for msgnumber " + msgnumber);
            client.quit();
        }
    });
...
```

Comment: *I used* `console.log(JSON.stringify({obj:mail_object}));` *to get the data of mail_object to the parent.* - well, all that does is send output to the console

Comment: It sounds like whatever it is giving you when there is an attachment might not be valid JSON? You might want to get the value of `retValue` and put it into a [JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/) for some help debugging it. If the attachment contains double quotes that aren't being escaped in the JSON that could cause that kind of error.

Comment: How to fix if the double quotes aren't being escaped?

Comment: I think the problem here is , I used spawn so the attachment that it returned are not yet completed